# Matlab moving average

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I tried to create a function named `moving_average.m`, which has as parameter an array
of any length and calculates the moving average from three successive values. The result shoud return an array. This is my current code:

```
function [output] = moving_average(inputarray)
    sz = size(inputarray);
    output = zeros(sz);
    for i=1:sz
        output(i,:) = (inputarray(i) + inputarray(i+1) + inputarray(i+2))/3;
    end
    
end
```

Right now, it only sets the first element of the output array and the others a zero. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function, then run the function. It’ll stop at the breakpoint and let you examine the contents of variables, and step through the function line by line. Step to after you define `sz` and examine its value. Is this what you expect? What is the result of `1:sz`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing a 3-point moving average, the `for` loop is trying to access values `i`, `i+1`, and `i+2`, but they don't exist. This is how I would rewrite the function `moving_average`:

```
function [output] = moving_average(inputarray)
    len_z = length(inputarray);
    output = zeros(len_z-2,1);
    for i=1:len_z-2
        output(i) = (inputarray(i) + inputarray(i+1) + inputarray(i+2))/3;
    end

end
```

Then test it with the following:

```
X = rand(20,1);

moving_average(X)
```

I use a `20x1` vector as the input `X`, but it will work with any `nx1` or `1xn`. The output of `moving_average(X)` will be `(n-2)x1`.

Comment: If that first paragraph was right, OP would get an error message, but they’re not. Only the first element of the output is set. This answer does not explain why. In your code, you replaced OP’s `size` with `length`, which fixes OP’s issue, but you don’t explain why you make this change. The explanation you give addresses the issue you run into after fixing OP’s issue.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `size` function is a Nx1 array, where N is the number of dimensions of the input.

```
inputarray = rand(1,20);
sz = size(inputarray)
```

output:

```
sz =

    1     20
```

The statement `i = 1:sz` expects a scalar value. Therefore Matlab just looks at the first element of `sz`, which is 1 for a 1xN array. If you use a Nx1 row array, it will run N times, but then you will get an error (`Index exceeds array bounds.`) because it will then try and access rows N+1 and N+2, which don't exist. This is why you need to use `for i=1:sz-2` as shown by Martin.

The `length` function is equivalent to `max(size(A))`. This is handy as it seamlessly handles row and column vectors.